# Is it possible to create a ES6 Javascript expression whose value is an object with a dynamic property name?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I currently do:

```
function outer(prop_name) {
    const tmp = {};
    tmp[prop_name] = 'hello world';
    foo(tmp);
}
```

Is there a way of rewriting this as:

```
foo(<expression>)
```

using an expression involving `prop_name`?

Comment: if foo is you function u can return object in outer and then do foo(outer());

Comment: Yes, that is a solution to the example, but that doesn't answer the question "Is it possible to create a ES6 Javascript expression whose value is an object with a dynamic property name?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write it as

`foo({ [prop_name] : 'hello_world'});`

Comment: Wow, that works.  It looks like it was new in ES6.